# Adding Javascript Confirm Dialog to LinkButton/Form generates Object Expected error

Tags: asp.net, javascript, object-expected

I am attempting to add a javascript confirm dialog to either my linkbutton onclick event or my form onsubmit event.

Neither of them work as I receive an 'object expected' error from the browser.

```
frm.Attributes.Add("onsubmit", "return Confirm('Really do this?')")
```

How do I add a confirm dialog to the 'onsubmit' or 'onclick' events without generating an 'object expected' error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

confirm method should be all lowercase letters

Ex

```
confirm('Really do this?')
```

Answer (score 0):

use `OnClientClick="return confirm('Message')"`

Answer (score -1):

Still using those legendary conform boxes. How about some JQuery BlockUI?

http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#dialog